# need to eliminate null from rows having same data

Tags: sql-server

my data:-

```
UserId |ShopId  |PlanName
------------------------
241    | 17679  |NULL
241    | 20037  |NULL
241    | 20037  |440
```

the data that i need :-

```
UserId |ShopId  |PlanName
------------------------
241    | 17679  |NULL
241    | 20037  |440
```

this is my query

```
select distinct so.UserId,so.ShopId, (select sa1.beatplanid from beatplansetting bps1 
inner join shopassign sa1 on bps1.beatplanid = sa1.beatplanid
where
so.shopid = bps1.shopid
and
sa.userid = sa1.userid
) as PlanName from 
shopinandoutlog so
left join beatplansetting bps on so.shopid = bps.shopid
left join shopassign sa on so.userid = sa.userid and bps.beatplanid = sa.beatplanid
where so.userid=241
and
convert(varchar,mobiletransactiondate,106)='01 oct 2016'
and
so.shopid in (20037,17679)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you want:

```
select UserId, ShopId, MAX(PlanName) as PlanName
from t
group by UserId, ShopId;
```

I don't know what your query has to do with the actual question.  Your query has multiple tables and columns not mentioned in the query or sample data.